# How to Order Visual studio Unit test methods without Ordered Test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

I have 5 Unit test methods I want to order them.

How to do in VS2013?

Kindly guide me.

I have tried Ordered test but i need those method names to be displayed in Test explorer.

Comment: Are you using the built-in testing framework, or something else?

Comment: Yes i am using Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework

Answer (score 3):

If your Unit Tests need to be ordered you're doing it wrong.

`[TestInitialize]` and `[TestCleanup]` methods are ok, but you shouldn't be chaining them,  or linking Unit Tests in order. This defeats the purpose.

Aim to have small, encapsulated, independent tests that stand on their own.

**Edit:**

> method names to be displayed in Test explorer

There is no need. Order them in TestExplorer or name them with a prefix.

Comment: I couldnt get you .. can you please explain

Comment: Maybe you could start by elaborating **why** you need the tests ordered?

Comment: I have a project that has create update delete functionalites ..  How i can achieve this by step by step ... Like First Create then update then delete ..  kindly guide me

Comment: So you don't really need them ordered in Test Explorer, you need them ordered because you need to first INSERT, second do some tests, thrird DELETE. In this case you need to look into some existing frameworks that do this for you - elegantly. One that comes to mind is [White](https://github.com/TestStack/White) or just perform that in your [`TestInitialize]` and [`TestCleanup]`

Comment: I think you mean the `[TestInitialize]` and `[TestCleanup]`, I don't think MS-Test has a setup or tierdown (teardown?) attributes.